# MYSQL GROUP BY day , week, month to display those statistics

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table named revenue and has a column named `datedone` (`DATETIME`)
I wanted to group my records by `day`, `week`, and `month` depends on the value of `datedone` for e.g.

```
ID: 1 | rate: 99.99 | datedone: 2019-11-02 04:11:22

ID: 2 | rate: 99.99 | datedone: 2019-10-31 13:20:26

ID: 3 | rate: 99.99 | datedone: 2019-11-02 04:07:39
```

Here is query that I tried:

```php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM revenue WHERE datedone = '$month' GROUP BY MONTH(datedone)";
```

But it return me this

```
ID: 2 | rate: 99.99 | datedone: 2019-10-31 13:20:26

ID: 3 | rate: 99.99 | datedone: 2019-11-02 04:07:39
```

What I want is display all the records for specific month, for example if I want to choose the month of `november` It should display all the records that the values of `datedone` has a `november` month, same with day and week.

Comment: A group by is designed to work with aggregate functions. You want to display all records for a specific month so a where clause is appropriate.

Comment: Check my updated query.

Answer (score 1):

If you want all the rows from november, you'd have do do this:

`SELECT * FROM revenue WHERE MONTH(datedone)=11;`

Comment: Oh great, but how to achieve that in daily and weekly of current month?

Comment: If you want a particular week, you'd use `WEEK()` function. But I suspect that you want ALL the records. If so, you can use `ORDER BY` to sort them for you.